# How do I look for objects with a particular property with a particular value using Python in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, properties

I have a number of objects with the boolean property, and I need to write a script which specifies any object which has this property and whose value is set to True. I don't know how to phrase a definition for such an object though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bge

def findObjectByPropertyValue(propertyName, propertyValue):
    return [object for object in bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
            if propertyName in object and object[property] == propertyValue]
```

Alternative *(This does not allow to search for value None as it can't distinguish between value None and not-present)*:

```
import bge

def findObjectByPropertyValue(propertyName, propertyValue):
    return [object for object in bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
            if propertyName.get(property) == propertyValue]
```